# Is it possible mount two separate tmpfs filesystems during boot?

Tags: mount

When i execute the df command i can see that tmpfs is mounted on /. What i need is to create a directory in /etc, say tmp and then mount another tmpfs on /etc/tmp. Can i do it by adding another entry in /etc/fstab saying tmpfs should be mounted on /etc/tmp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example (in /etc/fstab)

```
tmpfs    /etc/tmp    tmpfs    defaults,size=50%      0       0
```